# R: Error in as.Date.numeric(value) when using is.na() on data

Tags: r

I am having issues with using is.na() to change NA to zeroes within a data frame. Initially, I am changing the date format. As an example, the code format is like this:

```
Date <- c("16/08/2010 08:00", "17/08/2010 08:00", "18/08/2010 08:00")
Data1 <- c(30,NA,40)
Data2 <- c(50,60,NA)
df <- data.frame(Date,Data1,Data2)

df$Date <- strptime(df$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz = "GMT" )
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, origin = df$Date[1])
df[is.na(df)]<-0
```

which yields the correct result. However, when I apply the same code to my data, I receive the error which I cannot figure out:

```
Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

When I use str(data) the output is:

```
str(data)
'data.frame':   19461 obs. of  6 variables:
$ Date    : Date, format: "2008-01-28" "2008-01-28" "2008-01-28" ...
$ NO_flux : num  NA 5.33 NA -5.92 -10.87 ...
$ NO2_flux: num  NA -12.7 NA -11.5 18.8 ...
$ N2O_flux: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ NH3_flux: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ O3_flux : num  NA 313.42 NA 228.41 3.46 ...
```

Comment: Change to zero first and drop the `strptime()` line, `df <- data.frame(Date,Data1,Data2); df[is.na(df)] <- 0; df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"); df`

Comment: Thanks Richard - that seems to have done it!